# Find a polynomial mod $n$ injective on a given set

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

This question is inspired by [this challenge on CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26270/hash-collision-no-means-yes), in which the goal is to create a hash function with specified collisions.  I thought a polynomial over the integers mod $n$ might be a nice solution, but realized I didn't know a good way to come up with one.

Let me phrase the question as follows.  Let $n$ be an integer and let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$.  I do not wish to assume that $n$ is prime (I have in mind $n = 2^{32}$). Let $A \subset R$ with  $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in R \setminus A$.  Let $m = |A|$ and assume $m \ll n$.

> **Problem.** Find a polynomial $p$ over $R$, of minimum degree, such that $p(x_1) = p(x_2)$ and the restriction $p|_A$ is injective.
>
> Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?

Trivially we can find a solution of degree $m$, by setting $p$ to take whatever values we desire on $A \cup \{x_2\}$.  But since I don't care what values $p$ takes on $A$, so long as they are distinct, it seems we might be able to reduce the degree a lot.  For all I know, there might even be a solution of degree 3.

A crude approach might be to be take $p(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)q(x)$, where $q$ is some random polynomial, and check exhaustively whether $p|_A$ is injective.  Given that $m \ll n$, it seems that this would succeed with high probability, but it is inelegant, and it might not be easy to ensure that $p$ was of minimum degree.

Of course, the question might also be interesting with $R$ replaced by another finite commutative ring.  We could also ask to be able to prescribe more values for $p$ outside $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n\mid k^2$ and $p\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[X]$ with $p(0)=p(k)$, then $p(0)=p(2k)$.

*Proof:*
Consider the polynomial $q(X)=p(kX)-p(0)$. We have $q(0)=q(1)=0$. We can drop all monomials of degree $\ge 2$, hence as a function $q(X)$ is like $aX+b$ with $a.b\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. From $q(0)=q(1)=0$, we have $a=b=0$, hence $p(2k)=q(2)=0$. $_\square$

Corollary: If additionally $n\not\mid 2k$, no polynomial for $A=\{0,2k\}$, $x_1=0$, $x_2=k$ exists.

Comment: Good observation.  It so happens that with the original problem we have $|A| = 18278$ so with $n=2^{32}$ this doesn't directly arise.  It could upper-bound the degree of a solution, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, with $n=2^{32}$, you run into problems as soon as any difference of two eleemnts of $A$ is a multiple of $2^{17}$